# Is the minimum eigenvalue a convex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let A be a symmetric real matrix. Let $f(A)=λ_{min}(A)$

I know that the maximum value is a convex function. But is this true for the minimum? Can we repeat the reasoning for the infinum?

Comment: Or about a concave function?

Comment: Hint: $\lambda_\min(A)=-\lambda_\max(-A)$

Comment: No, I'm wondering if it is convex

Comment: Thank_______You